# In pytest, how can I figure out if a test failed? (from "request")

Tags: python, testing, selenium, pytest

I'm using Selenium with PYTEST to test a site. I would like to take a screenshot of the page whenever a test fails (and only when it fails).

Is there a way that I can do this? The docs are quiet when it comes to this (or I can't find it). I would assume that it would be something like

```
request.function.failed
```

and it would return a boolean or something.

This is what I wanted to do:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def something(request):
    if request.function.failed:
        print "I failed"
```

This would be added to a finalizer, of course. Can it be done? Using pytest 2.3.3

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It can be done, not directly though.  I just [added an example to the docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#making-test-result-information-available-in-fixtures).  It probably makes sense to makes this easier by default, i.e. without requiring the use of a conftest.py hook.  If you agree, please [file an issue](https://bitbucket.org/hpk42/pytest/issues/new).

Comment: [Filed it](https://bitbucket.org/hpk42/pytest/issue/230/make-getting-test-results-from-fixtures). Not sure if I gave enough info (assigned to you).

Comment: NB issue is now at https://bitbucket.org/pytest-dev/pytest/issue/230/make-getting-test-results-from-fixtures (repo was moved)

Comment: And the issue is now here: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/230

Answer (score 10):

I had to do something similar on a per-module level. After examining the existing solutions I was a little surprised by their complexity. Here's an approach I came up with to address this issue:

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="module", autouse=True)
def failure_tracking_fixture(request):
    tests_failed_before_module = request.session.testsfailed
    yield
    tests_failed_during_module = request.session.testsfailed - tests_failed_before_module
```

It can be tweaked to do what you want by making the fixture a function-level one.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This solution does not deal with tests running in parallel, it's behavior will be unpredictable.

Comment: I don't have much context on how tests are run in parallel in pytest but I suspect there is an easy way to safely share state across parallel runs in a similar fashion. Good point though.