# Detect whether test has failed within fixture

Tags: testing, pytest

I am debugging an intermittent test failure. For this purposes I want to dump a lot of debug information if a test failed. Dumping debug stuff is quite slow process which produces a lot of data, so I do not want to do this for every test.

I am using pytest and yield autouse fixture should work great

```
@pytest.yield_fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def dump_on_failue(request):
    prepare_debug_dump()

    yield

    if test_failed(request):
        debug_dump()
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how do I detect whether test has failed or not. There was [a questions already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364868/in-pytest-how-can-i-figure-out-if-a-test-failed-from-request) and even note [on pytest website](http://pytest.org/dev/example/simple.html#making-test-result-information-available-in-fixtures):

```
    if request.node.rep_setup.failed:
        print ("setting up a test failed!", request.node.nodeid)
    elif request.node.rep_setup.passed:
        if request.node.rep_call.failed:
            print ("executing test failed", request.node.nodeid)
```

Unfortunately this code does not work anymore. There are no rep_setup and rep_calls symbols in node object. I tried to dig request and node object, but no luck.

Anybody knows how to detect whether test failed?

Comment: The `pytest_runtest_makereport` hook in the example you listed *adds* those `rep_*` attributes. Are you sure you added that as well?

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51830008/3162884 explains how to use pytest_runtest_makereport so that rep_* will be created

Answer (score 1):

> There are no rep_setup and rep_calls symbols in node object.

*No.rep_setup and rep_calls symbols are still there.*

Add this code into your root `conftest.py`. It will check pass/fail for every test function.

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.tryfirst
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call, __multicall__):
    rep = __multicall__.execute()
    setattr(item, "rep_" + rep.when, rep)
    return rep

@pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
def test_debug_log(request):
    def test_result():
        if request.node.rep_setup.failed:
            print ("setting up a test failed!", request.node.nodeid)
        elif request.node.rep_setup.passed:
            if request.node.rep_call.failed:
                print ("executing test failed", request.node.nodeid)
    request.addfinalizer(test_result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this, maybe it can be useful in your case:

```
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item):

    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()

    if rep.failed:
        if rep.when == "setup":
            print("Setup failed!")
        elif rep.when == "call":
            print("Test method failed")
    elif rep.passed and rep.when == "call":
        print("Test {} passed.".format(item.name))
```

Comment: Do you have complete example?